# How do you create React Native Stack Navigator screens based on the length of an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I have been trying to dynamically render React Native Stack Navigator screens based on how many foods there are in a database, I have tried several approaches but none have worked,to be clear the desired behavior is for one screen to render for each food in the database, with both the food name and food brand included in the screen, currently nothing is rendering. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, useEffect } from 'react-native';
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
import { initializeApp } from "@firebase/app";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import { getDatabase, ref, push, onValue } from "@firebase/database";

const appSettings = {
  databaseURL: "" //My url
};

const app = initializeApp(appSettings);
const db = getDatabase(app);
const foodsInDb = ref(db, "foods");

const HomeStack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function Search() {
    useEffect(() => {
        const handleData = (snapshot) => {
            let foodList = [];
            foods = Object.values(snapshot.val())
            for (let i = 0; i < foods.length; i++) {
              let foodBrand = foods[i][0]
              let foodName = foods[i][1]
              let screen = (<SafeAreaView key={Object.keys(foods[i])}>
              <Text>{foodName}</Text>
              <Text>{foodBrand}</Text>
              </SafeAreaView>)
              foodList.push(<HomeStack.Screen key={index} name={"Screen" + index} component={screen} />)
        }
        }
        onValue(foodsInDb, handleData)
    }, [])
    return (
            <HomeStack.Navigator>
                {foodList}
            </HomeStack.Navigator>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    button: {
        backgroundColor: "blue",
        padding: 10,
        borderRadius: 5,
        marginTop: 10,
    },
    buttonText: {
        color: "white",
        fontSize: 16,
        fontWeight: "bold",
        textAlign: "center",
    },
});
```

Comment: I think `onValue(foodsInDb, handleData())` should be `onValue(foodsInDb, handleData)`

Comment: `foodList` should also be created with `useState` and then updated in an `useEffect`

Comment: Also react-navigation suggest to avoid dynamically creating screens. You could have a single `FoodScreen`  that renders data base on the parameters it received when getting navigated to; and then `useRoute` to get those parameters